# Segmentation fault in QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, backtrace, qlist

I have a segmentation fault in the following code snippet - to summarize, I have a QStringList "**args**" which receives some data from **arguments()** which is a QList type:

```
    QStringList args = arguments();
    bool isOne = false;
    bool isTwo = false;

    for (QString arg : args) {
        if (arg.contains("some_string1")){
            isOne = true;
        }
        if (arg.contains("some_string2")){  
            isTwo = true;         
        }
    }
```

**arguments():**

**Type** -> QList m_arguments;

```
inline QList<QVariant> arguments() const { return m_arguments; }
```

Checking the backtrace, I get something like this:

```
arg = {static null = {<No data fields>}, d = 0x55abfd3e00}
__for_range = @0x7fe924feb8: {<QList<QString>> = {<QListSpecialMethods<QString>> = {<No data fields>}, {p = {static shared_null = {
        ref = {atomic = {_q_value = {<std::__atomic_base<int>> = {static _S_alignment = 4, _M_i = -1}, <No data fields>}}}, 
        alloc = 0, begin = 0, end = 0, array = {0x0}}, d = 0x55abfed8c0}, d = 0x55abfed8c0}}, <No data fields>}
__for_begin = <optimized out>
__for_end = <optimized out>
args = {<QList<QString>> = {<QListSpecialMethods<QString>> = {<No data fields>}, {p = {static shared_null = {ref = {atomic = {
        _q_value = {<std::__atomic_base<int>> = {static _S_alignment = 4, _M_i = -1}, <No data fields>}}}, alloc = 0, 
        begin = 0, end = 0, array = {0x0}}, d = 0x55abfed8c0}, d = 0x55abfed8c0}}, <No data fields>}
isMainApp = false
isNodeJS = false
```

Maybe is it because there are no arguments passed in args or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: what is "m_arguments"

Comment: QList<QVariant> m_arguments;

Comment: how is the m_arguments filled?

Comment: @AndreiDutan I don't think it is valid to assign a QList <QVariant> to a QStringList.

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ  I'm not sure how to answer this but what can I add is that the arguments might come in different format ( maybe chinese) and should I use some utf8 converter?

Comment: @eyllanesc doesn't QVariant has a constructor taking QString?

Comment: @AndreiDutan this type mismatch between QList<QVariant> and QStringList is definitely strange. You shouldn't be able to simply assign this, those are two different types! A QVariant can contain any Qt-Type (even a QStringList). You'd first have to check whether each QVariant contains a QString and then "get it out". See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html

Comment: @AndreiDutan 1) Can't assign QList <P> to QList <Q>, 2) If you could 1 then you should assign QStringList to QList <QVariant> but not the opposite, you want to assign a QVariant to QString.

Comment: @AndreiDutan You have to iterate over QList, convert each QVariant to QString and add it to the QStringList: `QStringList args;` `for(const QVariant & v: arguments()){ args << v.toString();}`

Comment: Ok, thanks all for the info!

Comment: @AndreiDutan all things aside, this code should not even compile in the first place.     `QStringList args = arguments();` should trigger the failure  (provided `arguments()` has the return type you mentioned). What compilation flags do you have on?